# SQL Update Join error

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I have had a read through a few of the other issues around joining on SQL Updates but haven't been able to finalise a query.

System is all in MySQL (INNODB table structure)

We are wanting to update an amount in one table that will increase an amount based on 2 variables from another table.  There are a few constraints that need to be checked in the update to make sure the variables from the second table match the keys in the table to be updated

> UPDATE as1 
>   SET as1.amount = as1.amount + (b1.workers * b1.level) 
>   FROM account_stock AS as1 
>   INNER JOIN building AS b1 ON as1.accountID = b1.accountID 
>   INNER JOIN building_seed AS bs1 ON bs1.buildingID = b1.buildingID 
>   WHERE bs1.stockID = as1.stockID 
>   AND b1.accountID = as1.accountID  
>   AND b1.locID = as1.locID  
>   AND b1.status = active  
>   AND b1.gTime > 0

It's getting an error and I can't pick it.  Sorry if it is a simple question, all my SQL is self taught so some of the habits I have aren't very good!

Comment: It looks like @ypercube has the answer, but for future reference it's always helpful to provide the error message as well.

Comment: Thanks @mellamokb - I will make sure to add that next time :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

MySQL syntax for [`UPDATE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/update.html) is different. There is no `FROM`:

```
UPDATE 
    account_stock AS as1
  INNER JOIN building AS b1 ON as1.accountID = b1.accountID
  INNER JOIN building_seed AS bs1 ON bs1.buildingID = b1.buildingID

SET as1.amount = as1.amount + (b1.workers * b1.level)

WHERE bs1.stockID = as1.stockID
  AND b1.locID = as1.locID
  AND b1.status = active
  AND b1.gTime > 0 ;

  --- removed duplicate : 
  --- AND b1.accountID = as1.accountID
```

Also: is `active` a column or you meant to write?: `AND b1.status = 'active'`

Comment: Thats the ticket!  Works a treat.   A few mistakes on my behalf of column names but the query structure is perfect.

Thank you :)